# Why the class.click method doesn't work?

Tags: html, onclick

I am beginner at web programming. I am trying to assign click method to a className. But it doesn't work and no solution on the internet worked for me. How can I fix this problem?

My simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ada</title>

<style>
.menu{background-color:green;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).on("click",".menu",function()
{
alert("Hello World");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" class="menu" value="click!" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery library file

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js

```
  $(document).on("click",".menu",function()
{
alert("Hello World");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uq8zf0m4/

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>ada</title>

    **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>**


<style>
.menu{background-color:green;}
</style>

    <script>
        $(document).on("click",".menu",function()
        {
            alert("Hello World");
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" class="menu" value="click!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st. Make sure you're referencing the Jquery api in your scripts tag in the head elements.

2nd. A good tutorial and easy to read reference for beginners 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp